# Was solar newbie Solar Orbiter able to get "closer" to the Sun than Parker Solar Probe so quickly?

Tags: nasa, the-sun, esa, parker-solar-probe, esa-solar-orbiter

The NASA News headline [ESA/NASA's Solar Orbiter Returns First Data, **Snaps Closest Pictures** of the Sun](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/solar-orbiter-returns-first-data-snaps-closest-pictures-of-the-sun) caught my eye because [Solar Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Orbiter) (2020-010A) was launched just five months ago whereas [Parker Solar Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) (2018-065A) has been on its way to the Sun for 23 months!

**Question:** Was solar newbie Solar Orbiter able to get "closer" to the Sun than Parker Solar Probe so quickly? Or did Parker just not take pics of the Sun yet?

Comment: I figured you would find the following useful (unfortunately there's a paywall so let me know if you can't access it):  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576520306512

Comment: @honeste_vivere I find it very exciting and won't get anything useful done otherwise until I read it all the way through :-D btw it seem they've made that paper open access, yay!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Other spacecraft](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2018/parker-solar-probe-breaks-record-becomes-closest-spacecraft-to-sun) have been closer, but none have carried Sun-facing imagers.

Source: [The link you provided](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/solar-orbiter-returns-first-data-snaps-closest-pictures-of-the-sun)

("Other spacecraft" is linked to an article about Parker Solar Probe)

**Q:**  Or did Parker just not take pics of the Sun yet?

**A:** Yes, or at least not from a distance closer than Solar Orbiter

Answer (score 4):

Check [these visualization](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4653)s from NASA. Solar Orbiter will never get as close as Parker Solar Probe perihelion. That's why it can operate a camera pointed directly into the Sun and why it didn't have to wait for better shielding technology to arrive.

> The goal is to get the spacecraft *(Parker Solar Probe)* to fly through
> the corona at a distance of 9.5 solar radii. Primary science
> operations are conducted when the spacecraft is within 0.25
> astronomical units (AUs) from the Sun,

> The primary science operations for Solar Orbiter are conducted when
> the spacecraft is within 0.5 AUs from the Sun.

9.5 solar radii are equal to 0.044 AU. From 0.5 AU down to 0.044 AU the heat load increases by a factor of 129.